# Angular 2 @Input directive syntax for SVG attributes to avoid lint no-input-rename warning

Tags: angular, svg, angular2-directives, tslint

I'm writing an attribute directive for an SVG element:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[pinchresize]'
})
export class PinchResizeDirective {
  @Input('attr.width') width: number;
...
}
```

The `width` attribute is a valid SVG attribute and has to be specified in the template via `attr.width`:

```
<g pinchresize [attr.width]="component.width">
```

As coded the directive works correctly but it appears this isn't the desired syntax according to tslint:

```
[tslint] In the class "PinchResizeDirective", the directive input
property "width" should not be renamed.Please, consider the following
use "@Input() width: string" (no-input-rename)
```

If I use the generic syntax specified by `tslint` the width attribute is not initialized and is set to `undefined`:

```
@Input() width: number;
```

I'm having trouble coming up with the correct syntax for this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just

```
@Input() width: number;
```

should do what you want.

`[attr.xxx]` is special binding syntax and that won't work if you name the input with an `attr.` prefix.

If you want or need attribute binding instead of property binding you can use

(doesn't work)

```
<g pinchresize [attr.width]="component.width">
```

This will create an attribute `width` with the value from `component.width` **and** will assign the attribute value to `@Input() width: number;`

```
@HostBinding('attr.width')
@Input() width: number;
```

with

results in

```
<g name="b" pinchresize="" ng-reflect-name="b" ng-reflect-width="55" width="55"></g>
```

with the `width="55"` attribute set **and** the value passed to the `@Input() width:number;`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do want attribute binding and I just tested again to confirm that using ``[attr.width]="component.width"`` and ``@Input() width: number;`` unfortunately does not assign ``component.width``'s value to ``this.width``. Inspecting ``this`` in the browser debugger does not show any attributes added.

Comment: I tried it and can confirm that attribute binding (`[attr.width]="...")` doesn't set the `@Input()` https://plnkr.co/edit/FQeAgIAGD0WLEENeA43v?p=preview. Might be worth a bug report. A workaround is to combine `@Input()` with `@HostBinding()`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks! In this scenario ``@HostBinding('attr.width') @Input()`` does work: https://plnkr.co/edit/Z02dFaIIv2wxpoM0pzV0?p=preview I'll have to see why my more complex actual scenario doesn't.